# Llamar una variable en un for in

Tags: javascript

Quiero poder unir esas dos clases o hasta más en el *for in* ya que la variable coge una ubicación automáticamente. Entonces me interesa poder acceder a lo que se encuentra en el JSON

```js
// EJEMPLO SIN EL FOR IN

cities = {
  "citie1": {
   "citieInfo": {
    citie_info: 'etc...',
    citie_stock: 'etc... 2'
   }
  }
}

alert(cities.citie1.citieInfo.citie_info);


// LO QUE NO LOGRO HACER 

var ciudad1 = "citie1";

var spaces = [];


// AQUÍ NO SE CÓMO UNIR A LAS DOS VARIABLES 
for (spaces in cities.ciudad1 o cities + ciudad1) {

document.write(cities...[spaces].citie_info);

}
```

Comment: ¿Y `cities.ciudad1` en dónde lo defines? Sería en todo caso `cities[ciudad1]` y `spaces` ya está definido y se está usando fuera de scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un `for in` te da el nombre del índice y recorre los elementos de una colección

```js
// EJEMPLO SIN EL FOR IN

cities = {
  "citie1": {
   "citieInfo": {
    citie_info: 'etc...',
    citie_stock: 'etc... 2'
   }
  }
}

var ciudad1 = "citie1";

for (indexName in cities[ciudad1]) {

 console.log(cities[ciudad1][indexName].citie_info);

}
```

De forma que vamos a recorrer cada elemento en `cities[ciudad1]` y obtendremos el nombre de la propiedad